Not All WebSocket Message Rendered until Fast Refresh
I am trying to load my Python script and presented in a web app. Here I am using Next JS and frontend and Django Channels (web socket) as backend. When I am trying to test the code, only the first line is shown but not others. The remaining lines are shown after the Fast Refresh.
Here are my code:
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [log, setLog] = useState(null);
  const [showLog, setShowLog] = useState(false);

  const url = 'ws://localhost:8001/ws/simulation/'
  const ws = new WebSocket(url);
  let consoleLog = [];

  ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    setShowLog(true);
    console.log(event.data);
    consoleLog.push(event.data);
    setLog(consoleLog);
  };
  useEffect(() => {ws.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log("Connection opened");
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({"pk": 1, "action": "test", "request_id": 1}));
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <div className="crud-header"><h1>Run</h1></div>      
    <div id="console">
      {showLog && log.map((line, index) => <div key={index} id="console-line"><p>{line}</p></div>)}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

My questions are:

Why only print first line live?
Why other lines are not printed until Fast Refresh?

Ultimately I am trying to print all the log lines live.
